# Certain applications hanging every few seconds, stops with external monitor

Tags: graphics, troubleshooting

I have an issue on my laptop where the graphical output of certain applications seems to hang every few seconds, but other than graphically hanging the application seems to carry on working, eg, audio still plays, key presses and mouse scrolls still register. The cursor still moves with the mouse during the hangs.

Affected:

- Firefox 69
- Gwenview 19.08.1

Not affected:

- Chromium 77
- xterm 349

I can't see any messages in dmesg or journalctl when the hangs occur and the CPU doesn't seem to jump. **Plugging in an external monitor stops the issue**, this is the only way I've found to stop it so far.

I have a Dell 9550 with an Intel 530 and an Optimus Nvidia GM107M. It does not appear to make any difference whether I enable or disable the Nvidia card. I am using dwm, not Gnome.

I have tried the following kernel boot parameters which did not work:

- [acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-234494238)
- acpi_osi="!Windows 2015"
- [nvidia-drm.modeset=0](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-234494238)

And the environmental variable [__GL_MaxFramesAllowed=1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1202)

I think the Nvidia issues have probably just been a distraction as I don't appear to be using the Nvidia drivers and the issue happens when the Nvidia card is disabled. However I assume it must be something to do with the graphics card(s) since plugging an external monitor in fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by removing the Intel Xorg driver and relying on the modesetting driver.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1866301#p1866301